# Dynamic Array with Pointers to Objects in Out-Parameters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, openssl

I have a function that fetches several `X.509` certificates from a server. I want it to "return" an array of those certificates in OpenSSL's `X509 *` structs. But since my interface returns error codes, I want to use an out parameter.

If I am not mislead this would require me to use a pointer with 3(!) `*` (e.g. `X509 ***certs`). I am here because I personally find that highly confusing. Here is what I plan on doing and I would like to know if I am completely on the wrong track (it seems to me):

```
int get_certs(X509 ***certs)
{
    X509 **local_certs;
    int i;
    local_certs = malloc(no_of_certs * sizeof(X509 *));
    // fetch certs
    for(i=0; i < no_of_certs; ++i)
    {
        // load single cert into variable "cert"
        local_certs[i] = cert
    }
    *certs = local_certs;
}
```

A call would then look probably like this:

```
X509 **certs;
get_certs(&certs);
```

Is this the correct approach to it? Because to me this triple-pointer seems just weird.

*Note*: I don't know how many certificates there will be so it must be a dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the right-left reading rule... `X509 ***certs` means that certs is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a X509. So, if you want to return a `X509**` to the caller, the caller needs to pass you an `X509***` for you to store it in.

Also, I'm not sure your logic for dealing with a single cert is correct... it should look like this (imo) -- note the extra malloc inside the for loop.

```
int get_certs(X509 ***certs)
{
    X509 **local_certs;
    int i;
    local_certs = malloc(no_of_certs * sizeof(X509 *));
    // fetch certs
    for(i=0; i < no_of_certs; ++i)
    {
        X509* cert = malloc( sizeof( X509 ) );
        // load single cert into variable "cert"
        local_certs[i] = cert
    }
    *certs = local_certs;
}
```

An alternative would be to return a `X509**` from the function...

```
X509** get_certs( int no_of_certs )
{
    X509 **local_certs;
    int i;
    local_certs = malloc(no_of_certs * sizeof(X509 *));
    // fetch certs
    for(i=0; i < no_of_certs; ++i)
    {
        X509* cert = malloc( sizeof( X509 ) );
        // load single cert into variable "cert"
        local_certs[i] = cert
    }
    return local_certs;
}
```

Comment: 1. The extra malloc is not necessary as `cert` is correctly allocated by the source. 2. Returning is not an option, that has to be an error code.

Comment: Fair enough... then the answer to your question is given in the first paragraph of my answer and the rest is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I had it wrong, I knew it *felt* wrong. Here is the first problem: If returning it this way, how do I know how many certs are in there? I don't. But OpenSSL has already solved that with so-called stacks:

```
int get_certs(STACK_OF(X509) **certs)
{
    STACK_OF(X509) *local_certs;
    int i;
    // load variable local_certs with content
    // in my case that is a PKCS#7 data structure
    *certs = local_certs;
}
```

I shortened my data source, as I already know it but its more complicated. This looks a lot better and OpenSSL now offers some functions like `sk_X509_push` or `sk_X509_num`. This is a nice abstraction and solves my problem.